# Share Image to third party apps in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, xiaomi

I'm trying to share image with third party apps in android. I'm able to share image with all device except Xiaomi(Android 12) & OnePlus Node (Android 11).

```
 val shareIntent = Intent()
 shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText)
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri)
 shareIntent.type = "image/*"
 shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using"))
```

Shows toast message --> this file is not supported.

Comment: Start by replacing `image/*` with the actual MIME type of the content identified by `imageUri`.

Comment: i tried this but this can't solve issue

Comment: You might want to update your [mcve] to show what you tried, and to show how you got the value for `imageUri`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val file = File(path, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png")
    file.outputStream().use {                 
           imageBitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, it)
                }
    var imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
                    file )
```